# Can't FTP or SSH after getting new Router

Tags: router

I have separately tried to set up 2 new routers on my home network (a Linksys and an Asus). While each was easy to set up and I connected to the Internet, with neither of them was I able to FTP or SSH from my desktop (Windows 7 Home Premium, LAN/cable connection to router) to servers on the Internet.  I assumed it was firewall, but even after I completely disabled that, I could not connect.  Each time, when I put my old router back on I was able to FTP and SSH again. I also configured the old router myself, and it has no unusual or "power user" settings.  Just "out of the box" with password updates, etc., exactly like the two new ones.

I rebooted everything (router, cable modem, computer) multiple times, etc., with each router.

I know there must be something obvious that I am missing...  any ideas?

Comment: You say you have 2 routers, how are they set up?  Does one run through the other on the way to the modem?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  I tried two separate routers in succession, not at the same time.  When I couldn't get the Asus to work, I tried the Linksys, with the same results.

Comment: Regarding error messages, all my FTP client and SSH client say is that it timed out.

Comment: @RickFree did you found a solution?